# Matplotlib Nested Events

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am working on re-making a GUI in python for some data analysis that was previously done in Matlab. One functionality I need is to be able to look at a particular plot of data and select which part of the plot is background. I am using matplotlib to do my plotting, and I am trying to use mouse and keyboard events to handle this functionality.

My question, then, is how I can "activate" an event, in my case using the mouse to select background data, by using a keystroke event to tell the program to look for mouse input.

To map out what I would like:

Press "ctrl+b" to enter background selection mode
Then:
  click once to grab leftmost x data
  click again to grab rightmost x data
  disable click input

Any suggestions?

For reference, here is a bit of my attempt; the "ctrl+b" part works, then freezes after the first click.

```
def background(event):
    print('button=%s, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' % (event.key, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
    if event.key == "ctrl+b":
        print("You clicked ctrl+b")
        xbounds = []
        while len(xbounds) < 2:
            cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

def onclick(event):
    xbounds.append(event.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, figured it out myself... the while statement is running indefinitely and causing python to crash. Switching while to if solved the problem.